# how to measure the current from AC-DC supplier?

Tags: power-supply, dc

I started to learn the AC/DC circuit some times ago. I don't have much experience. But from this semester on, I have some chances to practice it in lab by working on some project. I got a AC/DC power supplier with 12VDC/1.5A output. I want to verify the current is really 1.5A with a meter by connecting a big resistor in series with the meter and the cable, but it gives 3A output instead of 1.5A. I don't understand what cause that, is any wrong I did to measure the output current?

By the way, I check the DC voltage output with the meter too and it gives 12V. I wonder what will show if I use VAC function to measure the DC output? Should I get zero? But very strange it reads 3 to 5V instead.

Comment: Have you tried connecting your AC voltmeter to a battery to see what you measure? You might be surprised to see on ac it can also read dc voltages. This does happen with some meters.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting AC voltage is that you're pulling more than the rated current, so your output has a ripple in it. If you're drawing too much current, the output filter capacitors will be incapable of "smoothing" the AC (from either the switch-mode transformer, or the linear transformer -- whatever the PSU is using). So, although you may be getting 12V, it's pretty nasty 12V.

I bet if you increased your load's resistance a bit (therefore decreasing current consumption), you'd see the AC voltage drop to near-zero. Otherwise, it's not much of a DC power supply, now is it!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What I am not comfortable is that the DC said to be of constant voltage and current output but it seems that the actual output really depends on the load, isn't it? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Many power supplies will allow more than their rated current, but must reduce the voltage in order to compensate. You will have to simultaneously measure both the current through and the voltage across the load, and vary the load until both are within tolerance from their listed ratings.